# Django Heroku pipfile lock out of date

Tags: django, heroku, python-venv, pipenv

So I recently moved from pipenv to venv, now that I try to push my changes to Heroku, I'm getting:

```
-----> Installing pip 23.3.1, setuptools 68.0.0 and wheel 0.41.3
-----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2023.7.23
       Your Pipfile.lock (old_hash[-6:]) is out of date. Expected: ({new_hash[-6:]}).
       Usage: pipenv install [OPTIONS] [PACKAGES]...
```

How can I migrate to venv and not use pipenv anymore in Heroku? should I delete my pipfilelock? or should I go back to pipenv?

Comment: Pipenv and venv don't do the same thing. What do you mean by "migrate to venv"?

Comment: thanks for responding, I used to use only pipenv and with that have my virtual environment, I got rid of it to use venv

Comment: Do you mean you got rid of it to use _pip?_ Again, Pipenv and venv aren't the same kind of tool.

Comment: (Pipenv does manage virtual environments, but that's not very relevant for deploying to Heroku. I'm pretty sure you're talking about dependencies.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pipenv does a few different things, including dependency management and virtual environment management. In the context of a Heroku deployment it makes more sense to ask about dependencies than virtual environments. I *think* you're trying to switch from Pipenv to *pip*, not venv.

Heroku uses Pipenv over pip if Pipenv configuration files are found. In this case, pip is skipped entirely.

### If you've already switched to pip locally

pip doesn't use `Pipfile` or `Pipfile.lock` files at all.

If you've already switched your local workflow to pip and already have an up-to-date `requirements.txt`, you can simply delete the `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`, commit, and redeploy.

### If you don't have an up-to-date requirements.txt

If you don't yet have a `requirements.txt` file, or if it is out of date, you can [ask Pipenv to generate one for you](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced.html#generating-a-requirements-txt) from its lock file:

```
pipenv requirements > requirements.txt
```

By default, this will omit dev requirements. That's usually what you want when deploying to Heroku, but there are options documented in the linked page to handle dev requirements differently if you need to.

Then proceed with deleting Pipenv config files, committing, and redeploying as above.

Comment: Note that lock files are useful things, and pip doesn't directly support them. You might want to consider using something like [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools) to generate a pinned `requirements.txt` file that includes transitive dependencies (analogous to a lock file) from a more loosely-specified `requirements.in` file that only contains direct dependencies (analogous to a `Pipfile`). That's out of scope for this answer, though.